# I want to redirect to my admin page after I click the submit button

Tags: php

I am trying to redirect after I hit the submit button using the header function. It didn't work so I tried ob_start at the top then ob_clean at the bottom. But when I do that it automatically pushes me to the page I want to redirect to. Heres the code any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php 
ob_start();
// Create connection
require_once "../includes/db_conn.php";  

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


# Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
   echo 'connected';
       }

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$title   = $_POST['title'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$image   = $_POST['image'];

 }   


 $sql = "INSERT INTO article (`title`, `content`, `image`) VALUES ('$title', '$content','$image');";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$conn->close();

echo <<<END_OF_FORM
<form method='post' action='article_new.php'>

Title: 
<input type='text' value='$title' name='title'><br>

Content: 
<input type='text' value='$content' name='content'><br>

Image: 
<input type='text' value='$image' name='image'><br>


<input type='submit' value='new article' name='submit'>
</form>
END_OF_FORM;
ob_clean();
header('location: admin.php')
?>
<a href="admin.php">Admin</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle user input when its submitted. So put them inside the `isset($_POST['submit'])` block. If you want to redirect **after the insertion is done**, then make your process inside it, then redirect at the end. And you should use prepared statements instead as you are prone to SQL Injection.

You shouldn't show output before making any header redirects.

```
<?php 

require_once "../includes/db_conn.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $title   = $_POST['title'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $image   = $_POST['image'];

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    # Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO article (`title`, `content`, `image`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    $insert = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $insert->bind_param('sss', $title, $content, $image);
    $insert->execute();

    header('Location: admin.php');
    exit;
}

?>

<form method='post' action='article_new.php'>
    <label>Title: </label>
    <input type='text' name='title'><br>

    <label>Content: </label>
    <input type='text' name='content'><br>

    <label>Image: </label>
    <input type='text' name='image'><br>

    <input type='submit' value='new article' name='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: I am really new to programming andd was following along. thanks for the feedback. people down vote for anything on here. Is this not a valid question according to stacks guidelines?

Comment: @EdBanes i do not know about those other people who downvote, it could be myriad of things why, most likely because of the title of this question.

Comment: thanks @Ghost this worked. All the booksI have read, I have never seen question marks in the VALUES part of SQL. This is the professional way to do it rather than having variables?

Comment: @EdBanes i do not know what the professional way is, but using prepared statements makes you safe from SQL injection. im glad this helped. i suggest you read up on this as well http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

Why is the sql and the redirect outside the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` condition? Try something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $title   = $_POST['title'];
   $content = $_POST['content'];
   $image   = $_POST['image'];
   $sql = "INSERT INTO article (`title`, `content`, `image`) VALUES ('$title','$content','$image');";

  $result = $conn->query($sql);    
  $conn->close();    
  header('location: admin.php');
}   

echo <<<END_OF_FORM
<form method='post' action='article_new.php'>

Title: 
<input type='text' value='$title' name='title'><br>

Content: 
<input type='text' value='$content' name='content'><br>

Image: 
<input type='text' value='$image' name='image'><br>


<input type='submit' value='new article' name='submit'>
</form>
END_OF_FORM;
ob_clean();
?>
<a href="admin.php">Admin</a>
```

With this logic, your page will get redirected after the form is submitted and data is inserted in the db.

Comment: I was following along with a tutorial I am new to programming. And trying it the way you have it makes the screen blank accept for the admin link. and their is no connection to the database